# Dockerfile wget fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following code

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget     #install wget lib
RUN mkdir -p example && cd example     #create folder and cd to folder
RUN WGET -r https://host/file.tar && tar -xvf *.tar   # download tar file to example folder and untar it in same folder
RUN rm -r example/*.tar # remove the tar file
RUN MV example/foo example/bar # rename untar directory from foo to bar
```

But i get the following errors:

```
/bin/sh: 1: WGET: not found
tar: example/*.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I am a newbie in docker.

Comment: 'wget' in lowercase and then 'cd ..' before rm :)

Comment: I am pretty sure the last line should be changed from "MV" to 'mv" as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each subsequent `RUN` command in your Dockerfile will be in the context of the `/` directory. Therefore your `.tar` file is not in the `example/` directory, it would actually be in the `/` directory since your 'cd to the folder' would mean nothing for subsequent `RUN` commands. Instead of doing `cd example`, rather do `WORKDIR example` before running `wget`, eg:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget     #install wget lib
RUN mkdir -p example     # create folder and cd to folder
WORKDIR example/         # change the working directory for subsequent commands
RUN wget -r https://host/file.tar && tar -xvf *.tar   # download tar file to example folder and untar it in same folder
RUN rm -r example/*.tar # remove the tar file
RUN mv example/foo example/bar # rename untar directory from foo to bar
```

Or alternatively, add `cd example && ... some command` before any command you'd like to execute within the`example` directory.

Answer (score 7):

As Ntokozo stated, each RUN command is a separate "session" in the build process. As such, Docker is really designed to pack as many commands into a single RUN as possible allowing for smaller overall image size and fewer layers. So the command could be written like so:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    mkdir -p example && \
    cd example/ && \
    wget -r https://host/file.tar && \
    tar -xvf *.tar && \
    rm -r example/*.tar && \
    mv example/foo example/bar
```

Comment: more efficient.